# How to give margin to FAB so that FAB don't overlay bar items in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using floating action bar in the middle of bottomNavigationBar but here I am not getting proper space for FAB, I want to apply margin to fab so that it looks better than this...

I have attached an image to make it clear more..

and another thing, how can I give curve like image showing for fab button

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade100,
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Bottombar 3'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.home,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              label: 'Home'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.shop,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              label: 'Shop'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.feedback,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              label: 'Feedback'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.shopping_cart,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              label: 'Cart'),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just create a BottomAppBar instead of the BottomNavigationBar and add the shape property to it:

```
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Icon(Icons.card_giftcard),
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
              shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(), //Add this property to the BottomAppBar
              color: Colors.redAccent,
              notchMargin: 5,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.menu,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.print,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.people,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```